# Umbraco CMS. Set image dimensions in uploader?

Tags: umbraco, uploader

I'm new to Umbraco. I am using Umbraco 5 RC2. I have noticed that when using the uploader to upload images. e.g. the example book area that it saves q image the original size and one which is 100px wide.  How can I change the these sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you're not able to set the image dimensions on the uploader, Umbraco comes shipped with a nifty little component called `ImageGen` which takes care of most of your needs for displaying images on your website. The code to use this component can be as simple as:

```
/umbraco/ImageGen.ashx?image=myimage.jpg&width=200
```

Refer to [ImageGen](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/imagegen) for complete documentation on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually we have moved away from Umbraco now anyway.  Version 4.7 seems to be fraught with errors and there's just not much out for 5 as its RC.